# How to render reactive png image for display and download in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create a shiny app that both displays a png that is created by the code (i.e. reactive) and which can then be downloaded. I found a nice example on how to create and update the png ([link](https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/build/images/)), but have not found out how to then grab this file for download. The download button is not working as intended.

The code below shows a minimal example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("renderImage example"),
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:",
                min = 0, max = 1000,  value = 500)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    # Use imageOutput to place the image on the page
    imageOutput("myImage"),
    # Download button
    downloadButton("download", "Download Image")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$myImage <- renderImage({
    # A temp file to save the output.
    # This file will be removed later by renderImage
    outfile <- tempfile(fileext = '.png')

    # Generate the PNG
    png(outfile, width = 400, height = 300)
    hist(rnorm(input$obs), main = "Generated in renderImage()")
    dev.off()

    # Return a list containing the filename
    list(src = outfile,
         contentType = 'image/png',
         width = 400,
         height = 300,
         alt = "This is alternate text")
  }, deleteFile = FALSE)
  
  # Enable image download
  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      "generated_plot.png"
    },
    content = function(file){
      # Save the plot/image to a file
      img <- system.file(output$myImage$outfile, package="png")
      file.copy(img, file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to display your image and want to download it, then IMHO the easiest approach would be to create your image inside a `reactive` which could then be used or called both in `renderImage()` and in `downloadHandler`. Also note that `system.file(output$myImage$outfile, package="png")` does not make sense. Instead when you store the list containing the image information as a reactive `image` as I do below you could use `image()$src` to get the file path.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("renderImage example"),
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:",
      min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500
    )
  ),
  mainPanel(
    imageOutput("myImage"),
    downloadButton("download", "Download Image")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  image <- reactive({
    outfile <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")

    png(outfile, width = 400, height = 300)
    hist(rnorm(input$obs), main = "Generated in renderImage()")
    dev.off()

    list(
      src = outfile,
      contentType = "image/png",
      width = 400,
      height = 300,
      alt = "This is alternate text"
    )
  })
  
  output$myImage <- renderImage(
    {
      image()
    },
    deleteFile = FALSE
  )

  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      "generated_plot.png"
    },
    content = function(file) {
      img <- image()$src
      file.copy(img, file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]